# What is this? I found it in tofino, Vancouver island

Tags: species-identification, marine-biology

[image]

I'm wondering what this sea creature is that I found washed up on McKenzie beach in Tofino, Vancouver Island? It wasn't dried up or anything. I've seen hundreds before but I cant find anywhere on the internet what they are!